# replace None value in dictionary by python (1 key , 3 value)

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I would like replace that "None" or "" (empty string) with "NoString" in my dictionary by python , i think a lot of time , but i can't finish it.

this is the dictionary:

```
{
'Column0':['ID','Company','Name'],
'Column1':[293193,'Exist','Robort Car'],
'Column2':[None,None,""],
'Column3':[None,"Close",None],
'Column4':["",None,None]
}
```

maybe i will use for and if ,please help me

Comment: How did you try to solve this task? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: You should check out `pandas`. It is much better for dealing with this type of data. If you're using a dictionary, yes, you will use a loop as you have multiple values to check and you need to check each key. Definitely check out `pandas` if you plan to do more with this type of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key here is to understand how to modify values of of a list. a simple for loop over a list would not modify / update values of a list. To do this, one has to use Enumerate, and access the element by index, to be able to successfully modify the value. I would also propose to use isinstance just out of my practice, because imagine a value not to be a list, then I do not want my code to break, and it is not that difficult to secure the code by using isinstance(...,list) per say.

Here is a more basic, easy to understand solution.

```
d = {
'Column0':['ID','Company','Name'],
'Column1':[293193,'Exist','Robort Car'],
'Column2':[None,None,""],
'Column3':[None,"Close",None],
'Column4':["",None,None]
}

print(d)

for k in d.keys():
    l = d[k]
    if isinstance(l,list):
        for idx, i in enumerate(l):
            if l[idx] is None:
                l[idx] = "NoString"

print(d)
```

and the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over dict values where you can replace them:

```
myDict = {
'Column0':['ID','Company','Name'],
'Column1':[293193,'Exist','Robort Car'],
'Column2':[None,None,""],
'Column3':[None,"Close",None],
'Column4':["",None,None]
}

newDict = dict()
for key, value in myDict.items():
    newDict[key] = ["NoString" if s in [None, ""] else s for s in value ]

print(str(newDict).replace("],", "],\n"))
```

output:

```
{'Column0': ['ID', 'Company', 'Name'],
 'Column1': [293193, 'Exist', 'Robort Car'],
 'Column2': ['NoString', 'NoString', 'NoString'],
 'Column3': ['NoString', 'Close', 'NoString'],
 'Column4': ['NoString', 'NoString', 'NoString']}
```